# How should I use EditorFor() in MVC for a currency/money type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, currency

In my view I have the following call.

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cost) %>
```

I have a ViewModel with the following code to define Cost.

```
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

However this displays a decimal value with four digits after the decimal (e.g. 0.0000).  I am aware of `Decimal.toString("G")` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx)) which appears to solve this issue, but I'm uncertain of where to apply it.

One solution seems to be create a partial view "Currency.aspx".

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Decimal>" %>
<%= Html.TextBox(Model.ToString("g"), new { @class = "currency" }) %>
```

And a `[UIHint("Currency")]` in my ViewModel.

This seems inelegant.  I assume that this problem has been solved tidily somewhere in the MVC framework or C# but I am unaware of cleaner solutions.

What is the appropriate way to handle editing currency values in MVC?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

and in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cost) %>
```

and that's all.

You will probably want to apply a custom CSS class. You could do this:

```
<div class="currency">
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cost) %>
</div>
```

and then have in your css:

```
.currency input {
    /** some CSS rules **/
}
```

or [write a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609072225/http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which will allow you to:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[HtmlProperties(CssClass = "currency")]
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

and then in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cost) %>
```

Comment: No @class = "currency" in this version.

Comment: This is great if you only have a couple currency fields to show editors for.  If you will be repeating throughout your application, the Currency.aspx approach is appropriate.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I tried to attempt the same with TextBoxFor and failed. I have explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700873/round-off-4-digit-decimal-to-2-digit-in-mvc-3-textboxfor. Seems like InputHelper class not considering FormatStrings :(

Comment: @Murali, it's normal that you failed. The `DisplayFormat` attribute is intended to be used with templated helpers such as `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor`. You cannot use it with `TextBoxFor`. I have posted an answer to your question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, the article you link to for "a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider" is using MVC 2 and Ascx files. Do you know of another tutorial covering MVC 4 or 5 and especially with Razor?

Comment: @JohnDubya, no, I don't know of an equivalent article for Razor. But it should be pretty trivial to adapt the code.

Answer (score 3):

This is the appropriate way if you are using EditorFor templates.

What does "inordinately inelegant" mean?

Comment: It means there is a lot of ugly code in the solution.  Solving a formatting error, that should be directly addressed by either language or framework (we are talking about currency types, not some obscure idea), should not require 3 lines of code across two files, neither of which actually contain the call to EditorFor().

Comment: @Thomas Langston ROFL!  You're using a metadata based template engine that removes hundreds of lines of boiler plate html + c# code and somehow 3 lines across two files is too much?