# Why MetadataType doesn't do my validation in database first approach?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-first, metadatatype

I used Database-First to generate a model class (EDMX file), and I want to validate using "MetadataType". I read solutions here but they didn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieEntitiesMetaData))]
public partial class MovieEntities
{        
}

public class MovieEntitiesMetaData
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public Nullable<global::System.Decimal> PRICE { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything missing here, or why did my solution did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file called `MoviePartial.cs` and place the following code inside it:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetaData))]
public partial class Movie
{    
    internal sealed class MovieMetaData
    {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
        public decimal? PRICE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You also need to pass the `Movie` type to the view so that the data annotations can be wired up. If you have a custom view model the data annotations won't get in action.

In the Create/Edit view you must have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PRICE)
```

In the Details view you must have:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PRICE)
```

For more on this, just follow this nice step by step tutorial:

[Validation with the Data Annotation Validators (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

Comment: I changed the code but still did not work, how to pass the MovieEntities to View?

Comment: What's the name of the object your view is going to consume? Is `MovieEntities` the name of your data context or is it the table name that came from the database?

Comment: MovieEntities is the name of the Model/ConnectionString that save in web.config the table name Movie. But I change the class to Movie still did not work. Here is the model in the beginning on my View @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.MOVIE>

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the name of your entity - in this case `Movie`. Now, in your Controller action named `Create` just pass a new `Movie` object to the View and place `@model MvcApplication3.Models.MOVIE` at the top of the view file. You should see the validation in action. By the way: you did not specify any validation for the `Price` property. I'll add the `[Required]` one. See my answer. For a complete tutorial, see the link I provided you.

Comment: Beside validation, I want to add display format for currency I think it work the same. But the display still the same as before. Is there any missing code that I left behind?

Comment: Edited my answer. Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5080451/114029

Comment: I change the metadata to [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Required")] but the validation won't work. I don't how to use it. I used database first to generate model so I cannot edit file .cs that generated from visual studio. Could you help solved this issue?

Comment: You must create a file called `MoviePartial.cs` and add the code in my answer to that file.

Comment: I have tried to create MoviePartial.cs but the validation and displayformat still did not work. The view is same as you mention on your answer. Is there any step that I need to do?

Comment: You must add a reference to jquery, jquery-validate and jquery-unobtrusive scripts in your `_Layout.cshtml` file.

Comment: What should I add jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js or jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js? I just add jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js but did not work. My class that contain table is MovieEntities and the table represent with Movie Class, is there anything wrong about my information that give it to you?

Comment: You should add `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Comment: Still did not work. I think the error is in the model class, I also do that about the link you gave me. Is that because I did not add Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll? I used ASP.net MVC 3

Comment: Sorry my bad, the problem solved because I named my class MOVIE not movie so your answer has worked already. Thanks for your help

Comment: Question, will this work if I want to inherit from IValidatableObject?

Comment: @Vyache yes... you can still do your validation with `IValidatableObject`.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi, can you provide an example? I'm not able to do it. I have my data annotations in a private sealed class. The partial class inherits from BaseEntity, IValidatableObject and so you know, this is a database first. I'm not able to validate my custom validation, but my sealed data annotation work just fine.

Comment: @Vyache why not? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3401178/114029 if it does not work, please ask a new questin here on StackOverflow and show us a sample of what you're doing and why it's not working. :)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi actually, I figured out the issue. The client side validations need to validate first before the IValidateObject.

Comment: @Vyache: in fact, client side validation is not tied to server side validation... you don't need client side val to do server side val. You mentioned `IValidatableObject` which is server side val. Anyways it's nice to know you got the result expected.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi Sorry I meant that I wanted to do both. Thanks for the help.