# DisplayFormat for TextBoxFor in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to round off 4 digit decimal to 2 digits and show in MVC 3 UI

**Something like this 58.8964 to 58.90**

Tried following this [How should I use EditorFor() in MVC for a currency/money type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080451/how-should-i-use-editorfor-in-mvc-for-a-currency-money-type) but not working.

> As i am using TextBoxFor=> i removed ApplyFormatInEditMode here. Even
>   i tried with ApplyFormatInEditMode , but nothing works. Still showing
>   me 58.8964.

MyModelClass

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")]
 public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.TotalAmount)
```

***How can i achieve this round off?***

**I can't use EditorFor(m=>m.TotalAmount) here, as i need to pass some htmlAttributes**

Edit:

After debugging with MVC source code, they internally use

```
 string valueParameter = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

in MvcHtmlString InputHelper() method of InputExtension.cs that takes  **object value** as parameter and converting. They are not using any display format there. How could we fix?

I managed to fix in this way. As i have a custom helper, i can able to manage with the below code

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelMetaData.DisplayFormatString))
   {
     string formatString = modelMetaData.DisplayFormatString;
     string formattedValue = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, formatString, modelMetaData.Model);
     string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
     string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
       return htmlHelper.TextBox(fullName, formattedValue, htmlAttributes);
   }
   else
   {
       return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
   }
```

Comment: Try using `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Comment: @Karthik, Sure. But let me try debugging MVC source code and see where it is setting like that

Comment: `We now allow passing in HTML attributes in EditorFor as an anonymous object` from [MVC 5.1 update](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `Html.EditorFor` instead of `Html.TextBoxFor` if you want the custom format to be taken into account:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TotalAmount)
```

Also make sure that you have set `ApplyFormatInEditMode` to true:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
```

The DisplayFormat attribute is intended to be used only with templated helpers such as `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor`. This is the recommended approach instead of using `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: But i need to pass html attributes.

Comment: Why MVC team can consider this as fix and implement for next release?

Comment: Why would the MVC team consider such a thing? I don't think that this is a bug. You should be using templated helpers anyway. Personally I always use `Html.EditorFor` and never `Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: Yes correct. But the EditorFor not accepting htmlAttributes as a parameter. :(

Comment: But why do you need such parameter? By the way you could write a custom model metadata provider as illustrated in the following blog post: `http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx`

Comment: The form is generated based on the fields defined in the database. Some fields are readonly and some fields are special. So i need to add a class like 'highlight' for special fields and 'readonly' attribute for read only fields. Also the field has a type defined in DB like textbox, dropdown etc. So i created my custom control factory class to generate!

Comment: Updatd my previous comment, which has more information on what i need.

Comment: That looks really nice. I follow implementing my own custom model metadata provider. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Why would I want to add a property? Perhaps for jquery/javascript reasons?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, Great news, `We now allow passing in HTML attributes in EditorFor as an anonymous object` from [MVC 5.1 update](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, is that possible to set invariant culture?

Answer (score 53):

This works in MVC5

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalAmount, "{0:0.00}")
```

Comment: Great, use this formatter "{0:N0}" if you want to avoid decimal point and Symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
@{
     var format = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.TotalAmount);
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalAmount, format)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is not working. Also you are passing the formatted value to a htmlAttributes parameter

Comment: i used this approach for a date. i couldn't use EditorFor since it doesn't let you specify classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control of the field being displayed (vs. a built in EditorFor template) create a custom EditorFor template yourself. Inside an EditorFor template, the built in Html Helpers like `@Html.TextBox()` can be used with **automatic client side validation and Display attributes** which are usually only available to `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor`.

For example looping through a List of items. The input name has to have an unbroken index.

```
// Optional, if you require a custom input name for binding
String fieldName = String.Format("FieldNameForBinding[{0}].Property", index)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property, "MyCustomEditorTemplate", fieldName)
```

Then you can setup your model

```
[CustomValidation(..optional..)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
```

The EditorFor template (in e.g. ~/Views/Shared/EditorFor/MyCustomEditorTemplate.cshtml)
Note the name is left empty, it comes from the  `fieldName` automatically. You can see it in the `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`. Now you have complete control over the display of the field.

```
@model object
@{
    Decimal? actualValue = (Decimal?)Model;
}
// The TextBox and ValidationMessage "names" are empty, they are filled   
// from the htmlFieldName given via the @Html.EditorFor() call.
@Html.TextBox("", actualValue, new { @class = "cssClass" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("")
```

The idea is that you can customize the input field however you would like, and use e.g. @Html.TextBox() which **outside** of a custom EditorFor template would not utilize the built in client-side validation. You don't need to use the custom naming of the input field, that was simply an example of the usefulness of this solution. You can customize the way the data is presented (CSS, etc.) instead of relying on the built in EditorFor templates.

Answer (score 1):

I solve that issue in this way:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtArrivalDate, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(model => model.dtArrivalDate, ViewData).EditFormatString)
```

or create next extension:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxWithFormatFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).EditFormatString, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

But you need to set `ApplyFormatInEditMode=true` in `DisplayFormatAttribute` on your field.