# DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat doesn't seem to support lists. Any way to get around it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a model with the following property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N1}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public List<decimal?> Scores { get; set; }
```

I was expecting it to be formatted with one decimal when printed like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.ContainingModelList[i].Scores[j])
```

It is not. It shows two decimals no matter what. If I try to implement a dummy property like this, formatting works though:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N1}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Test { get; set; } 
// Test is later initalized with 1.35443M and rendered as "1.4"
```

So... does the `DisplayFormat` attribute in combination with EditorFor not support lists? Any way to work around it?

*edit*: I meant EditorFor, but wrote DisplayFor

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700873/displayformat-for-textboxfor-in-mvc

Comment: Sorry my quasi-code was wrong, I meant and have tested for "EditorFor"

Comment: @Nilzor Did you ever find a fix for this? I am having the same problem

Comment: I honestly don't remember, and I don't have the source code anymore :(