# Razor MVC numeric format for textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textbox, in that i insert a number, the code are the following,

```
     @Html.TextBox("Semana1", "", new { @type = "number", @placeholder = "Ingrese Proyección", @maxlength = "15"   })
```

this textbox display a number 12356

I need that the textbox display a number with the format 123.456

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it like even if you enter `123.456` in textbox it displays ``123456`? Textbox changes this by itself?

Answer (score 2):

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalAmount, "{0:0.00}")

Useful link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669691/3397630

Answer (score 1):

You can use a step with your input. Add the below as an example.

```
@type = "number", @step = "0.01", @size = "6",
```